# Is $(x^2+y^2+z^2) \ \sin \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$ Differentiable in $(0,0,0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

$$f(x,y,z)=\begin{cases} (x^2+y^2+z^2) \ \sin \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} \qquad (x,y,z) \ne (0,0,0) \\ \\ 0 \qquad (x,y,z)=(0,0,0) \end{cases} $$

At first, I study the continuity in the origin. 
I apply the concept of sequential continuity: $x_n \rightarrow x_0 \Rightarrow f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x_0)$ 

So, $x_n=\frac{1}{n}  $
$$x_n \rightarrow 0 \Rightarrow f(x_n,x_n,x_n) \rightarrow f(0,0,0)=0$$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{3}{n^2} \ \sin \frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{n}}=0 $$

How can I continue the study of differentiation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't study the continuity of $f$ at the origin by choosing one sequence $\mathbf{p_n} = (x_n,y_n,z_n)$ that approaches $\mathbf{0}$ in a very specific way ($x_n = y_n = z_n = \frac{1}{n}$) and checking that $f(\mathbf{p_n}) \rightarrow f(\mathbf{0})$. You need to check that this works for **all** sequences converging to $(0,0,0)$ or, equivalently, check the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition. In your case, given $\varepsilon > 0$, if $|| \mathbf{p} - \mathbf{0} || = ||\mathbf{p}|| = ||(x,y,z)|| < \sqrt{\varepsilon}$ then

$$ |f(\mathbf{p}) - f(\mathbf{0})| \leq x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = ||(x,y,z)||^2 < \varepsilon $$

so indeed $f$ is continuous at $\mathbf{0}$. To check differentiability, check first whether the partial derivatives exist. For example,

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\mathbf{0}) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h,0,0) - f(0,0,0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h^2 \sin \left( \frac{1}{h} \right)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} h \sin \left( \frac{1}{h} \right) = 0. $$

Similarly, the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ exist and vanish. This means that if $f$ is differentiable,  we must have $df|_{\mathbf{0}} = \mathbf{0}$. Let us check that this is indeed the case (here, $\mathbf{p} = (x,y,z)$):

$$ \lim_{\mathbf{p} \to \mathbf{0}} \frac{f(\mathbf{p}) - f(\mathbf{0}) - 0 \cdot x - 0 \cdot y - 0 \cdot z}{||\mathbf{p}||} = \lim_{\mathbf{p} \to 0} \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} \sin \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}} \right) = 0 $$

and so $f$ is differentiable at $\mathbf{0} = 0$ with vanishing differential / gradient.

Answer (score 2):

It is much easier to analyze in spherical coordinates:

$$r^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$$

$$\theta = \operatorname{atan2}(y,x)$$

$$\phi = \arccos\left({\frac z r}\right)$$

$$f(r, \theta, \phi) = \begin{cases} r^2 \sin \left({\dfrac 1 r}\right); \ r \ne 0  \\ 0; \qquad\qquad \  r = 0\end{cases}$$

Now you can use Calc I methods to determine continuity.

Edit: Amended according to levap's excellent comments, you need to examine the definition of differentiability on $f$ at $\mathbf 0$, since the spherical coordinate system fails at the pole.

You need to check:

$$\displaystyle \lim_{\mathbf {r \to 0}}  {\frac{\vert f(\mathbf r) - f(\mathbf 0) - \mathbf {0 \cdot r}  \vert} {\vert \mathbf r \vert}} = \lim_{r \to 0} \left \vert {r \sin \left({\frac 1 r}\right)}\right\vert$$

and show it equals zero, which is the same as levap's answer.

Comment: Note that this is a bit dangerous to apply naively as a function such as $f(x,y,z) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$ which is represented in polar coordinates by $f(r,\theta,\phi) = r$ would appear to be differentiable at the origin.

Comment: @levap took me a bit to see the problem in that! But then $f = |r|$, good point. How should I qualify my answer?  Or should I delete it?

Comment: By studying a function using a coordinate system, we study $f \circ \varphi$ instead of $\varphi$. A coordinate system is usually assumed to be a diffeomorphism which guarantees that $f$ will be differentiable if and only if $f \circ \varphi$ will be differentiable but this fails for the spherical coordinate system at the origin. This doesn't mean that it can't be used to study differentiability properties of functions - only that some care is required.

Comment: You can say that by looking at $f$ in polar coordinates, you can suspect that $f$ is differentiable at the origin with zero differential and then check this by writing the definition of differentiability in cartesian coordinates as a limit and then calculating **only** that limit (which will be $\frac{f(r,\theta,\phi)}{r} = r \sin \left( \frac{1}{r} \right)$) using polar coordinates. In this case, this will amount to pretty much your argument but will guarantee that you won't make any mistakes.

Comment: @levap Excellent points, please proofread my amended answer.

Comment: This is somewhat delicate to nail precisely which is why I think I never saw a book that discusses this issue in full generality. Polar coordinates have as a domain $(0,\infty) \times (0,2\pi) \times (0,\pi)$ or if you want to have a good definition along the $z$-axis, on $[0,\infty) \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ (but then it is many to one and not defined on an open domain). Then one needs to say precisely what one means by the Jacobian of the polar representation of $f$ at the origin $\mathbf{0}$ (this is "one-sided" Jacobian in some sense along $r$).

Comment: So I would just write the limit as $\frac{f(\mathbf{r}) - f(\mathbf{0}) - \mathbf{0} \cdot \mathbf{r}}{\mathbf{r}}$ (which is the limit to check for if one suspects the differential is zero).