# Show that $(x^2 + y^2) \sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}\right)$ is differentiable.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

In this exercise one must show that $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
0 \text{     if } (x,y) = (0,0)\\
(x^2 + y^2) \sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}\right) \text{     else}
\end{cases}$$ is differentiable for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}$

In the lecture, we have proven that if all partial derivatives of $f$ exist and are continuous, then the derivative of $f(x,y)$ exists everywhere.

I start by calculating the partial derivatives of $f$ at $(0,0)$:
$$\partial_xf(0,0) = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x} = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{x^2\sin({1 \over x^2})}{x} = 0$$
Similar for $\partial_y$:
$$\partial_yf(0,0) = \lim_{y\to0} \frac{f(0,y)-f(0,0)}{x} = \lim_{y\to0} \frac{y^2\sin({1 \over y^2})}{y} = 0$$

We know that for all other values of $x$, $\partial_x f =
2x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right)-\frac{2x\cos
\left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right)}{x^2+y^2}$

I have tried to show that $\lim _ {x,y \to (0,0)} \partial_x f = 0$. (to show f is continuous) this however is problematic, since this limit doesn't exist.
This implies that the partial derivates are not continuous at all points. Which makes this approach of proving that $f$ is differentiable useless.

How do I prove that $f$ is differentiable on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I am open for all kind of suggestions. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Check here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818523/is-x2y2z2-sin-frac1-sqrtx2y2z2-differentiable-in-0-0-0  This shows that the fact the partial derivatives vanish at the origin saves the situation **in this case**. One of the classical examples that we do **not** have to have continuity of the partial derivatives to get differentiability...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that$$\tag1\lim_{(x,y)\to0}\frac{\bigl|f(x,y)\bigr|}{\bigl\|(x,y)\bigr\|}=\lim_{(x,y)\to0}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\left|\sin\left(\frac1{x^2+y^2}\right)\right|=0.$$Therefore, $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ and $D_{(0,0)}f$ is the null function, since, if $L\colon\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is the null function, then $(1)$ means that$$\lim_{(x,y)\to0}\frac{\bigl|f(x,y)-f(0,0)-L(x,y)\bigr|}{\bigl\|(x,y)\bigr\|}.$$So, by the definition of differentiable function, $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ and $D_{(0,0)}f=L\equiv0$.

Comment: Really sorry to ask. But how does $\lim_{(x,y)\to0}\frac{\bigl|f(x,y)\bigr|}{\bigl\|(x,y)\bigr\|}=\lim_{(x,y)\to0}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sin\left(\frac1{x^2+y^2}\right)=0. $ show that $f$ is differentiable. Why is it enough to show that the limit is $0$.

Comment: @David The denominator in fact is $\;|f(x,y)-0\cdot e_1-0\cdot e_2|\;$ , with $\;e_1,e_2\;$ two functions whatsoever...and the idea, of course, is that those two zeros take the place of the partial derivatives at zero...!

Comment: @David Don't be sorry for asking. I have edited my answer. I hope that all is clear now.